# Popup editor from a text area

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I want to be able to show an area where people can type text but on cursor focus, the editor tool bar will popup and also have the ability to expand as a model.  I want do exactly what is being done on http://demos.telerik.com/teampulse-demo/Authentication   when you editor a ticket.

see https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXkda.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with RadEditor for ASP.Net AJAX as shown in this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/toolbarmode/defaultcs.aspx

If you want to achieve this with Kendo UI editor see this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/inline-editing